# Rails using joins retrieve repeated column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord, pluck

My association

```
class Website < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :settings
  has_one :shop
end
```

Setting and Shop tables value are:

```
2.6.1 :003 > Setting.all.pluck(:records)
=> [2, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0]

2.6.1 :003 > Shop.all.pluck(:records)
=> [4, 1, 1]
```

Using joins

```
Website.joins(:settings, :shop).where("websites.id = ?", 2).pluck("settings.records", "shops.records")
```

I am getting repeated value

```
[[2, 4], [2, 1], [2, 1], [2, 4], [2, 1], [2, 1], [4, 4], [4, 1], [4, 1], [0, 4], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 4], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 4], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
```

The result i want like

```
[[2, 4], [2, 1], [4, 1], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

How can i resolve the problem?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `Website.joins(:settings, :shop).where("websites.id = ?", 2).pluck("settings.records", "shops.records AND settings.website_id = ? AND shops.website_id = ?",2,2).pluck("settings.records", "shops.records")` try this

Comment: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? AND shops.website_id = ?, 2 FROM `websites` INNER JOIN `setting' at line 1)` syntax error

Comment: `Website.joins(:settings, :shop).where("settings.website_id = ? AND shops.website_id = ?",2,2).pluck("settings.records","shops.records")` return same result

Comment: Can you provide the results of these two queries: `Shop.pluck(:website_id, :records)` and `Setting.pluck(:website_id, :records)` ?

Comment: `Shop: [[2, 2], [2, 2], [2, 4], [2, 0], [2, 0], [2, 0]] and Setting: [[2, 4], [2, 1], [2, 1]]`

Comment: Uh ... the record values you provided in the question and comment seem different, but I guess one of them is a typo. The join query would list all combination of settings and shops associated to the website whose id = 2 and `[[2, 4], [2, 1], [2, 1], [2, 4], [2, 1], [2, 1], [4, 4], [4, 1], [4, 1], [0, 4], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 4], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 4], [0, 1], [0, 1]]` is the expected result. I want to know why you expect that the query result is `[[2, 4], [2, 1], [4, 1], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]` ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you expect the result is `[[2, 4], [2, 1], [4, 1], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]`(maybe it is a typo?), but if you want to get the non-repeat result from the join query, you can use `group` + `distinct`:

```rb
Website.joins(:settings, :shop).where("websites.id = ?", 2).group("settings.records", "shops.records").distinct.pluck("settings.records", "shops.records")
=> [[0, 1], [0, 4], [2, 1], [2, 4], [4, 1], [4, 4]]
```